# How to replace hyphen and newline in string in Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, nlp

I am working in a text with several syllables divisions.

A typical string is something like that

```
"this good pe-
riod has"
```

I tried:

```
my_string.replace('-'+"\r","")
```

However, it is not working.

I would like to get

```
"this good period has"
```

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
import re

text = """this good pe-
riod has"""
print(re.sub(r"-\s+", '', text))
# this good period has
```

Answer (score 1):

After you match `-`, you should match the newline `\n` :

```
my_string = """this good pe-
riod has"""
print(my_string.replace("-\n",""))
# this good period has
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends how your string ends, you could also use `my_string.replace('-\r\n', '')` or an optional carriage return using re.sub and `-(?:\r?\n|\r)`

If there has to be a word character before and after, instead of removing all the hyphens at the end of the line, you could use lookarounds:

```
(?<=\w)-\r?\n(?=\w)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GKhmwJ/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/X5cjmS)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"(?<=\w)-\r?\n(?=\w)"
my_string = """this good pe-
riod has"""

print (re.sub(regex, "", my_string))
```

Output

```
this good period has
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland You are very sharp. (I wanted to say today, but you are always sharp :-))

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah, that is why I started the answer with `It depends how your string ends` like https://ideone.com/Qkmu32